# cleanest way to parse a text file with header C#

Tags: c#, filereader

I am reading from a .txt file with header. and everything is working fine. However, I have a question after looking at my final code. My code looks like following:

```
var fileReader = File.ReadLines("PathTOFILE")

foreach (var lineItem in fileReader.Skip(1))
{
    var propertyValues = lineItem.Split(null);

    listToReturn.Add(new NormData
    {
        prop1 = Convert.ToInt32(propertyValues[0]),
        prop2 = Convert.ToInt32(propertyValues[1]),

    });
```

Now, my question is that instead of referencing each item as `propertyValues[n]` is there a way in which I can somehow correspond the values with how header's values are listed and avoid using magic numbers to reference the values?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about reading CSV files... Clearly none of suggestion worked for you - would you mind include this information into the question?

Comment: There are many CSV tools to this for you.  At least one will read the file, parse the contents and store in a collection for you

Comment: Why do you want to add overhead to a perfectly fine running code? (The only thing I would add is a check for the exact number of items after the splitting)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why assume is cvs?

Comment: @LyubomirVelchev because it is... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values - header row plus rows of items separated by a whitespace based on code shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `int.TryParse`

To avoid referencing magic numbers you can define those in attribute for the properties of the class NormData then using reflection you can get the mapping.